# Using an ld version script in a cdylib Rust crate

Tags: rust, linker, ld

I am attempting to use a version script while building a `cdylib` Rust crate, however I am running into issues due to the anonymous version script created by the Rust compiler. I followed this [forum post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/linker-version-script/26691/5) on how to add a version script, but they never mentioned this issue.

### Execution

I'm using [`cargo-make`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-make) to build my project. In my `Makefile.toml` I have this task:

```
[tasks.build]
toolchain = "nightly"  # Running with nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
command = "cargo"
args = ["rustc", "--release", "-p", "my_crate", "--", "-C", "link-args=-Wl,--version-script=versions.map"]
```

Upon running `cargo make build`, that task executes this build command.

```
rustup run nightly cargo rustc --release -p my_crate -- -C link-args=-Wl,--version-script=versions.map
```

### Error

However, it keeps producing this error. From what I can tell, my version script (shown below) conflicts with an anonymous version script that gets generated by Rust (`/tmp/rustcyXUHTy/list` in the error). Unfortunately, the version script Rust generates is deleted immediately after creation so I don't actually know what it looks like. I attempted to follow [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468125/346556) to view the other version script, but it was deleted too quickly and I was unable to see the output.

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-Wl,--version-script=/tmp/rustcyXUHTy/list" ... "-Wl,--version-script=versions.map"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: anonymous version tag cannot be combined with other version tags
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

### Rust

```rust
// I'm not completely sure which tags should be used and so far they have had no effect on the error
// #[no_mangle]
// #[export_name = "foo"]
pub unsafe extern "system" fn foo() {}

// The crate also contains other functions which are not covered by my version script
// I tried removing all of the other #[no_mangle] functions, but it had no effect
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "system" fn bar() {}
```

### Version Script

I'm not very experienced writing version scripts so this is the simple test script I came up with. The final product will use a similar version script from an existing C project.

```
Project_1.0 {
    global:
        foo;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Solution provided by itamarst on the [Rust forums](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-use-linker-version-scripts-in-rust-1-54/64033).*

### Explanation

As shown in the question, `ld` does not support multiple version scripts. However, `lld` does so we can use that instead. (Can be installed with `sudo apt install lld` on ubuntu). To use `lld` instead of `ld`, pass `-Clink-arg=-fuse-ld=lld` to `rustc`.

However, this is not enough on its own. The version script Rust generates will take precedence and the version node will not be applied as specified in our version script. To get around this, functions can be given a temporary name and a new symbol can be linked to it via linker args (`--defsym`). In the version script the new symbol can be freely used and the original function name can be marked as local to prevent a duplicate symbols from being uploaded.

### Rust Code

```rust
// Name function foo_impl and rename it on the command line
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "system" fn foo_impl() {}
```

### Version Script

```
Project_1.0 {
    global:
        foo;
    local:
        foo_inner;
};
```

### Building

In a `cdylib` all of the rust/linker arguments can be configured in the `build.rs`.

```rust
// Tell Rust to use lld instead of ld
println!("cargo:rustc-cdylib-link-arg=-fuse-ld=lld");

// Set version script path
println!("cargo:rustc-cdylib-link-arg=-Wl,--version-script=mapfile");

// Rename symbols to get around the anonymous version script
for symbol in &["foo"] {
    println!("cargo:rustc-cdylib-link-arg=-Wl,--defsym={}={}_impl", symbol, symbol);
}
```

Alternatively, all of these arguments can be passed on the command line.

```
cargo rustc -- -Clink-arg=-fuse-ld=lld -Clink-args=-Wl,--defsym=foo=foo_impl,--version-script=mapfile
```